# Ag Grid Row Style [getRowStyle]="getRowStyle" geting error as param implicit has an any

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm using ag-grid as

```html
<ag-grid-angular [rowStyle]="rowStyle" [getRowStyle]="getRowStyle"
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Angular code as

```js
pubic export class Testingcomponent {
   getRowStyle = function(params) {
      if (params.node.rowIndex % 2 === 0) {
         return { background: 'red' };
      }
   };
   ...
}
```

at param i'm getting error as parameter 'params' implicitly has an 'any' type

i'm trying for getting alternate row colour but as per the documentation  `[getRowStyle]="getRowStyle"` we are passing any parameter & i'm getting error as param

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a type for `params`.

Solution 1 -

```
getRowStyle = function(params:any) { ...}
```

Solution 2 -

```
import { RowClassParams } from 'ag-grid-community';

getRowStyle: (params: RowClassParams) => { ... }
```